# How to remove 'Program Name: Adobe Photoshop' from the metadata?

Tags: photoshop, metadata, jpeg

I've tried all the solutions from here as well as from stackoverflow, the tool mentioned (ExifTool) won't remove the metadata. I'd like to remove all the Photoshop information from my jpeg, leaving the rest info as such. Can anyone please suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: For the record, even if you remove the 'Program Name: Adobe Photoshop' from the data, you aren't removing all of the other Photoshop artifacts.  The best thing to do is just use the original JPEG from the camera, if you're worried about the extra meta data.

Answer (score 10):

In Microsoft Windows, the tag "CreatorTool" is shown as "Program Name" in the file properties. This is why the tag "Program Name" can't be found by [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). it might also be the software tag that bothers you. In order to remove the tags, use the following command:

> exiftool -creatortool= -software= FILE

If you are using the [ExifTool GUI for Windows](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/) there is a button called Exiftool direct. Press it and you will get a command line interface input field. Write:

> -software= -creatortool= FILE

where **FILE** is the filename with the file extension e.g. myphoto.jpg

Comment: `exiftool -photoshop:all= FILE` also works for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to remove program name from the details tab of the file properties window, here's a trick I found. Open your jpeg with the unwanted program tag in microsoft paint and save as a png. Then open the file properties and in the filename field, manually change the extension to .jpg by erasing png and typing jpg. If your settings are like mine you will get a message that changing the extension could render the file unusable. Agree and check the details tab again, program name should be removed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that having a png file with a *jpg* suffix is bad practice.Moreover, you are modifying (degrading) the image by saving it with Paint.

Comment: I logged in to vote this up because in cases where degrading the image quality doesn't matter this was a great, quick and easy solution. Certainly shouldn't be down voted when there are very relevant use cases.